# How do i keep Label and Text input widget sizes the same inside a box layout in KIVY

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have an accordion layout and I am trying to figure out how to have varying numbers of widgets inside Box Layouts and keep them the same size as the other widgets in other Box Layouts.

I want to avoid using a Float layout as it gets a bit more time consuming and would think there should be a method to accomplish this using box layouts and size hints etc.

Currently I have 6 Box Layouts with a Grid Layout inside each of them to position the widgets appropriately, however, in some of the grid layouts i would like less widgets than some others and this causes the widgets to fill the remaining space regardless of whether i put a size hint in or not.

I have tried adding Labels in the Grid Layouts with no content but it does not change the sizing arrangement.  If I add the extra Text Input widgets it adjust to suit and is the same as the other Box Layouts but is not what i want.

Here is an image of what the code looks like so far: [image: App Example]

The top two box/Grid layouts with less widgets inside are the ones i want the same size as the other Box/Grid Layouts.

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Below is an extract of the .kv code: (I cut some out but apologies if it is too long)

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 18
    spacing: [10, 10]
    size_hint: [.5, .8]






<CustLabel@Label>:
    font_size: 18
    pos_hint: [None, None]
    color: 1, 0.757, 0.145, 1
    size_hint: [.8,.8]


<CustLabel2@Label>:
    font_size: 18
    pos_hint: [None, None]
    color: 1, 0.757, 0.145, 1
    size_hint: [.8,.8]


<CustTextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 18
    write_tab: False    
    size_hint: [.5,.5]
AccordionItem:
            title: "Water Figures"


            GridLayout:
                padding: [10,10]
                rows: 3
                cols: 0
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    padding: [10,10]
                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2
                        padding: [10,10]

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Port FW Tank Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: pfwtv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Stbd FW Tank Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: sfwtv
                            hint_text: "m3"

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Fire Fight FW Tank Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: fffwtv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2
                        padding: [10,10]

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Port DW Tank Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: pdwtv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Stbd DW Tank Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: sdwtv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    padding: [10,10]
                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2
                        padding: [10,10]
                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Today #1 Evap Meter"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ter_1
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Today #2 Evap Meter"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ter_2
                            hint_text: "m3"

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Previous #1 Evap Meter"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: per_1
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Previous #2 Evap Meter"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: per_2
                            hint_text: "m3"

                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2
                        padding: [10,10]

                        CustLabel2:
                            text: "Today Total FW Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ttfwv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Previous Total FW Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ptfwv
                            hint_text: "m3"

                        CustLabel2:
                            text: "Today Total DW Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ttdwv
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Previous Total DW Volume"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: ptdwv
                            hint_text: "m3"

                BoxLayout:
                    padding: [10, 10]
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    GridLayout:
                        padding: [10,10]
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "No 1 Total Evap Output"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: teout_1
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "No 2 Total Evap output"


                        CustTextInput:
                            id: teout_2
                            hint_text: "m3"

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Date"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: root.dt1
                            font_size: 25



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "Top Left"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: root.dt2
                            font_size: 25

                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        cols: 2
                        padding: [10,10]
                        CustLabel:
                            text: "To be determined"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustLabel:
                            text: "To be determined"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: "m3" 

                        CustLabel:
                            text: "To be determined"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: "m3"



                        CustButton:
                            text: "Calculate"


                        CustTextInput:
                            hint_text: "m3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `row_force_default: True` property to force the height of the rows. To specify the height you use the `row_default_height` property and binds it with the size of the rows of one of your complete gridlayouts, for example, using one of its widgets.

For example, using the `ptdwv` height as a reference:

```
GridLayout:
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: ptdwv.height
    rows: 4
    cols: 2
    padding: [10,10]
```

**Reproducible example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion


kv_text = '''
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 18
    spacing: [10, 10]
    size_hint: [.5, .8]

<CustLabel@Label>:
    font_size: 18
    pos_hint: [None, None]
    color: 1, 0.757, 0.145, 1
    size_hint: [.8,.8]


<CustLabel2@Label>:
    font_size: 18
    pos_hint: [None, None]
    color: 1, 0.757, 0.145, 1
    size_hint: [.8,.8]


<CustTextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 18
    write_tab: False    
    size_hint: [.5,.5]

<MyAccordion>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    AccordionItem:
        title: "Water Figures"
        GridLayout:
            padding: [10,10]
            rows: 3
            cols: 0
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                padding: [10,10]

                GridLayout:
                    row_force_default: True
                    row_default_height: ptdwv.height
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2
                    padding: [10,10]

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Port FW Tank Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: pfwtv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Stbd FW Tank Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: sfwtv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Fire Fight FW Tank Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: fffwtv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                GridLayout:
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2
                    row_force_default: True
                    row_default_height: ptdwv.height
                    padding: [10,10]

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Port DW Tank Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: pdwtv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Stbd DW Tank Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: sdwtv
                        hint_text: "m3"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                padding: [10,10]
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2
                    padding: [10,10]
                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Today #1 Evap Meter"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ter_1
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Today #2 Evap Meter"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ter_2
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Previous #1 Evap Meter"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: per_1
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Previous #2 Evap Meter"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: per_2
                        hint_text: "m3"

                GridLayout:
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2
                    padding: [10,10]

                    CustLabel2:
                        text: "Today Total FW Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ttfwv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Previous Total FW Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ptfwv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel2:
                        text: "Today Total DW Volume"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ttdwv
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Previous Total DW Volume"


                    CustTextInput:
                        id: ptdwv
                        hint_text: "m3"

            BoxLayout:
                padding: [10, 10]
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                GridLayout:
                    padding: [10,10]
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "No 1 Total Evap Output"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: teout_1
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "No 2 Total Evap output"

                    CustTextInput:
                        id: teout_2
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Date"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: '11/07/2017'#root.dt1
                        font_size: 25

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "Top Left"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: '20:00'#root.dt2
                        font_size: 25

                GridLayout:
                    rows: 4
                    cols: 2
                    padding: [10,10]
                    CustLabel:
                        text: "To be determined"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "To be determined"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: "m3" 

                    CustLabel:
                        text: "To be determined"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: "m3"

                    CustButton:
                        text: "Calculate"

                    CustTextInput:
                        hint_text: "m3"
'''
class MyAccordion(Accordion):
    pass
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyAccordion()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks again for your assistance.  It did exactly what i wanted.